# Textmeshpro not detecting TMP essential resources (NullReferenceException)

Tags: unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

I'm using Textmeshpro 3.0.6, and I am getting this error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object TMPro.TMP_Settings.get_defaultStyleSheet ()
> at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@3.0.6/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_Settings.cs:303

Whenever I get this unity also prompts me to import the TMP essential resources and Examples and Extra, which I already did. The strange thing is that a while ago it was working perfectly fine, but for no discernible reason I started to get this error. What could I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the TMP ressources and import again? Did you change the TMP version? Did you modify anything in the TMP resources?

Comment: it clearly thinks somethings missing.

Comment: I can confirm that I tried all of those things and it did not work.

Comment: Also I should add that the problem started when I updated to a pre-release version of TMP. I did that because it fixed an error I was experiencing in 3.0.6. At first it worked fine, but eventually I started getting this error, so I tried downgrading to 3.0.6 again, and the same thing happened: it worked fine at first (didn't even get the error that caused me to update in the first place), but then it stopped working again. The error message for the pre-release and 3.0.6 are different, but both prompted me to import essential resources.

Comment: I tried downgrading to 3.0.5 and the same thing happened. At first it fixed the error, but when I closed unity and re opened it, the error came back.